# How the GUID is generated by Metadata API and Manifest API of forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autocad, forge

**Guid** returned in the response of the **Metadata API**(https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/) and **Manifest API**(https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/manifest/urn-manifest-GET/) of forge is **autogenerated** or its **extracted** by the model. **If Yes then how can we access it in AutoCAD**?

Comment: I'm checking with our engineering team and will get back A.S.A.P.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, according to our engineering team, the GUID is randomly generated by the Model Derivative service. So, you cannot see it in AutoCAD. Sorry for the bad news.